# dump a message inside a queue in MQ (Linux)

Tags: linux, ibm-mq, mq

I want to dump a message from a queue in WebSphere MQ which is installed on a linux machine. How could I check messages inside queues with `mqm` authorized user? I have already checked inside `opt/mqm/bin` and I found some MQ commands like `dmpmqaut` and etc. But I can't find a command for dumping messages inside queues.

**EDIT-** I am using WebSphere MQ v.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to view messages on the queue if they are not too large in size is the `amqsbcg` sample program.

```
amqsbcg QUEUENAME QMGRNAME > output.file
```

This sample program can be found in
AIX/Unix: `$MQ_HOME/samp/bin/amqsbcg`
Windows: `$MQ_HOME\tools\c\Samples\Bin\amqsbcg.exe`

Where `$MQ_HOME` is the appropriate location for your operation system.  The default location for `$MQ_HOME` is:

AIX: `/usr/mqm`
Unix: `/opt/mqm`
Windows: `C:\Program Files\IBM\Websphere MQ`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I don't know why but I can not find amqsbcg command neither under opt/mqm nor under opt/mqm/bin. I think it is related to MQ version which I use.

Comment: It would be under opt/mqm/samp/bin as it is a sample program.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the path and post you the result.

Comment: Yup! I found it. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what version you are, but hopefully you are at a new enough version to have the `dmpmqmsg` command, This will dump the messages off the queue to a file.

If you are on an older version on IBM MQ that does not have this command, then the equivalent function can be used through [SupportPac MO03 QLOAD](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24009368). `dmpmqmsg` was the productisation of this free tool.

Comment: I am using WebSphere MQ 7.1 and unfortunately I don't have this command available. So any other solution?

Comment: This command was the productisation of the QLOAD SupportPac, editted answer to include pointer.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I remotely connect to this server and I am not allowed to make any changes to configurations. So, I can not instal supportPac on this machine. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Are you allowed to install things on the client machine?

Comment: I am afraid to say no. I can not install anything on this machine and the MQ version does not support dmpmqmsg!

Comment: Then your only option is to go with the samples you already have installed as per @ValerieLampkin's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of freeware/shareware programs to view/edit messages in a queue: http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools.html#msgedit

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at wrong path. please check the path again and you will find the "amqsbcg" under /usr/mqm/samp/bin( for AIX).